# Github - Removing collaborators after they fork a private repo

Tags: github, repository

My organization has a private repo and we've brought on a few contractors and given them access to the code base.

These contractors have been forking the code base, and I wanted to evaluate the potential security implications of that.

- Could any of these forkers make the code public if they choose to?
- If their access is removed from the original project, will their access to the forked repo also be removed?

Comment: Anyone with access to code (irrespective of VCS) can make it public - not exactly sure how this is specific to git or forking repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could any of these forkers make the code public if they choose to?

Yes, they can push it to a new public Git repo (on GitHub or any other Git hosting service)

> If their access is removed from the original project, will their access to the forked repo also be removed?

See "[Removing a collaborator from a personal repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-collaborator-from-a-personal-repository/)"

> While forks of private repositories are deleted when a collaborator is removed, the person will still retain any local clones of your repository.

For a better security, contractors usually operate on PCs inside the organization through VPN. Those PCs can then limit or prevent internet access.